# Xcode6 IPAD 1x 2x button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I was developing an app on iphone and let in run on my iPad.
Before Xcode 5, it will run happily with the 1x and 2x button at the right bottom corner so I can zoom to get a larger view of my iPhone app.

However, after Xcode6 appears, I found that my iPhone app act as a full screen app and the content appears at the top left corner without the 1x and 2x button when it runs on my iPad.

Any solution to change get back the 1x 2x mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Launch Screen, and in the options on right side, uncheck **"Use as Launch Screen"** option, it will work fine after that.