# 2.10 - iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, resolution

my app was rejected the other day, and I got this rejection message:

> 2.10 Details
>
> We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.3, which is a violation of the App
>   Store Review Guidelines. We’ve attached screenshot(s) for your
>   reference.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app to ensure it runs at iPhone resolution on iPad.

They also provided me with a screenshot, which I don't understand. I have tested the app on iPad and it seems to run perfectly. This is the screenshot I got:

[image: Apple Message]

I just can't seem to understand what is wrong on it. What do I have to change?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this a universal application?

Comment: It's supposed to be for iPhone only. (if that is what you ask). In xCode I've chosen iPhone as the only target.

Comment: Have you used size classes ?

Comment: Have you ever noticed that whenever we run an iPhone app on iPad, its size is smaller than the iPad's screen and it shows us a button like 2X to make it bigger. 
Do you get that button when you run it on iPad ?

Comment: No indeed, I don't get that button. What should I do to get it?

Comment: Did U solved this issue?

Comment: It honestly was just accepted after another try... This may have helped, not 100% sure anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199625/xcode6-ipad-1x-2x-button

Answer (score 1):

If you have developed an app specific for iPhone devices only, then whenever you run it on iPad for testing, its size should be smaller than the iPad's screen size. Also you should get a 2X button at upper right/left corner(not sure exact corner) to increase the size.

I have found this from a website,I hope it will help you

[image: Reply from Apple]

Comment: The "2x" button appears in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually don't get that button -- what should I do to get it?

Comment: Check your app settings and screen sizes, there may be some issue

Comment: I've checked but I can't seem to find what I have to change...My deployment target is iPhone only. What I do in my App Delegate is that for every different iPhone version I have a different Storyboard that I load (with a different size, etc.) instead of using the size classes. But for the iPad I don't do that.

Comment: Tried, cleaning your project ?

Comment: Go to the Product Menu in XCode, press the option key -- the "Clean" command (Shift + Cmd +K) changes to "Clean Build Folder" (Option+Shift+Command+K).

Comment: Also, I have found this on stackoverflow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420295/missing-2x-button-with-an-iphone-app-running-on-ipad

Comment: Check this too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199625/xcode6-ipad-1x-2x-button